# How to change language in Request (GET) URL?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, get, request

I am trying this code however still unable to change the language of the URL.

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamento-apartaestudio/arriendo/bogota/'
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
params = dict(lang='en-US,en;q=0.5')
response = get(url, headers = headers, params= params)
print(response.text[:500])
```

```
titles = []
for a in html_soup.findAll('div', id = 'divAdverts'):
    for x in html_soup.findAll(class_ = 'h2-grid'):
        title = x.text.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
        titles.append(title)
titles
```

Output

```
['Local en Itaguí - Santamaría',
 'Casa en Sopó - Vereda Comuneros',
 'Apartamento en Santa Marta - Bello Horizonte',
 'Apartamento en Funza - Zuame',
 'Casa en Bogotá - Centro Comercial Titán Plaza',
 'Apartamento en Cali - Los Cristales',
 'Apartamento en Itaguí - Suramerica',
 'Casa en Palmira - Barrio Contiguo A Las Flores',
 'Apartamento en Cali - La Hacienda',
 'Casa en Bogotá - Marsella',
 'Casa en Medellín - La Castellana',
 'Casa en Villavicencio - Quintas De San Fernando',
 'Apartamento en Santa Marta - Playa Salguero',
 'Casa Campestre en Rionegro - La Mosquita',
 'Casa Campestre en Jamundí - La Morada',
 'Casa en Envigado - Loma De Las Brujas',
 'Casa Campestre en El Retiro - Los Salados']
```

Does anyone know how can I change the language of the URL? Tried everything

Comment: To what language do you want to change the page? Is there some button on the page which changes the language?

Comment: It is in French I think, I want in English. I don't think so there is any button

Comment: It's in spanish. If there isn't any button, you need to translate it yourself, maybe with help of Google Translate or something.

Comment: Only setting the Accept Language Header won't change the language at all, its the server who needs to translate the content based on Accept Language, if the server is not handling that header, than you will get content always in the local language it is written in

Comment: It is Spanish or maybe Portuguese

Comment: I can translate it on the web using Google Translate. However, while using Python it is showing in Spanish. How to change it using get command? Or any other method I can translate it and get the above output in English?

Comment: You have to use other third party library such as this one `https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/`

Comment: I have no idea how to use that. Another issue, this is only one page I want to extract multiple pages. Have to learn that as well using Beautiful Soup

Comment: @Gaurav how to use this while extracting multiple pages? I saw the documentation. Can use this with a single page

Comment: @Parmeetsinghanand Only title is the field you will be extracting?

Comment: No, I want Price, Location, Bedroom and Size. These details are on the main page in the list view. Few more details if possible as they are not on the main page like description et cetera. They are available when we click a particular like. Right now no idea how to gather that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only giving example for particular field title, you may extend it to other fields, you may face issue `like being blocked by google for number of concurrent request` while using this library as it is not official one. Also you must consider to see the **Note** written in the documentation https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

```py
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
url = 'https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamento-apartaestudio/arriendo/bogota/'
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
params = dict(lang='en-US,en;q=0.5')
response = get(url, headers = headers, params= params)
titles = []
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for a in html_soup.findAll('div', id = 'divAdverts'):
    for x in html_soup.findAll(class_ = 'h2-grid'):
        title = x.text.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
        titles.append(title)
english_titles=[]
english_translations= translator.translate(titles)
for trans in english_translations:
    english_titles.append(trans.text)

print(english_titles)
```

Since you are scraping from spanish language to english language you can specify parameters in `translator.translate(titles,src="es",dest="en")`

Comment: The output is still in Spanish ['Apartamento en Cali - Nueva Tequendama', 'Casa Campestre en Mariquita - Ermita', 'Apartamento en Sabaneta - Asdesilla', 'Casa en Bogotá - San Cristóbal', 'Apartamento en Ibagué - Milla De Oro De Ibagué', 'Apartamento en Armenia - Avenida Centenario', 'Apartamento en Piedecuesta - Bellavista', 'Casa en Manizales - Sector Milán', 'Casa Campestre en Pereira - Cerritos']

Comment: What is result.text?

Comment: its title sorry while updating code  missed that one

Comment: one more thing can you help me extract the title from all the pages there are 632 pages in total. This could be used but I don't know-how: 'https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamento-apartaestudio/arriendo/bogota/?ad=30|'+ str(page_number) + '||||2||8,22|||67|3630001||||||||||||||||1|||1||griddate%20desc||||||'

Comment: you need to iteratively send the request over the url until you get a  failure response code. and the string you added in comment has changing number when you change the page, so in each request you need to pass this string as query params with updating page_number in each iteration